# Getting error when adding package to Spacy pipe

Tags: machine-learning, spacy

I'm getting an error while adding a spacy compatible extension, [med7](https://github.com/kormilitzin/med7), to the pipeline. I've included the replicable code below.

```
!pip install -U https://med7.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/en_core_med7_lg.tar.gz
import spacy
import en_core_med7_lg
from spacy.lang.en import English
med7 = en_core_med7_lg.load()

# Create the nlp object
nlp2 = English()
nlp2.add_pipe(med7)

# Process a text
doc = nlp2("This is a sentence.")
```

The error I get is

```
Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got spacy.tokens.doc.Doc)
```

I realized I was having this problem because I don't understand the difference some components of Spacy. For instance, in the [Negex extension package](https://pypi.org/project/negspacy/), loading the pipeline is done with the Negex command:

```
negex = Negex(nlp, ent_types=["PERSON","ORG"])
nlp.add_pipe(negex, last=True)
```

I don't understand what the difference between `Negex` and `en_core_med7_lg.load()`. For some reason, I when add "med7" into the pipeline, it causes this error. I'm new to Spacy and would appreciate an explanation so that I can learn. And please let me know if I can make this question any more clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`med7` is already the loaded pipeline. Run:

```py
doc = med7("This is a sentence.")
```

Comment: Sorry i dont follow. if i load med7 it adds it to the pipeline and doesnt load it in a separate object? I want to use med7 and other spacy packages on the same text.